# Searching and orderby with full name but first name and last name in seperate columns without using whereRaw Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 8 and I have a table with a combined column of `first_name` and `last_name` the problem is I can only search it by either the `first_name` only or `last_name` only, not with the full name, would be better if I can have an option to `orderBy` it by full name also. I'm trying to avoid the whereRaw as much as possible as I've researched to have very hard performance especially in large tables.

This is my search function (How to search using combined `first_name` and `last_name`)

```
    public function scopeSearch($query, $term)
    {
        $term = "%$term%";
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($term) {
                $query->where('type', 'LIKE', $term)
                    ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', $term)
                    ->orWhereHas('level', function($query) use ($term) {
                        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $term);
                        })
                    ->orWhereHas('employee', function($query) use ($term) {
                        $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', $term);
                        $query->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', $term);
                        $query->orWhere('employee_number', 'LIKE', $term);
                        })
                    ->orWhereHas('status', function($query) use ($term) {
                        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $term);
                        })
                    });
    }
```

And this is my table query (How to orderBy combined `first_name` and `last_name`)

```
            $models = Model::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
            ->search(trim($this->search))
            ->orderBy($this->column, $this->order)
            ->paginate($this->size);
```

Comment: If the last_name is more important, order first by first_name and then last_name. No need to concat. As a side note, not sure why you use anonymous functions inside of anonymous functions. You have your reasons. In a small table, no problem. With millions of entries, it could become a sql request time issue. You could consider polymorphic relationships if the project is still in construction. Just an honest observation.

Comment: But wouldn't that make it 2 orderBy lines? Sorry, but wdym by anonymous functions? I've research about the polymorphic relationships and would consider this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `FULLTEXT` index across all the columns.  It will be *much* faster.

Comment: Laravel doesn't support full text to my knowledge? How do you apply this.

Comment: Condolences.  That is a recurring problem with the hundred packages that try to hide MySQL from the programmer.  This forum is littered with "how to work around the limitations of X".

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
        SELECT CONCAT(`first_name`, ' ', `last_name`) as full_name FROM `users`;
```

However, you must make it in the subquery so that laravel can know what is **full_name**

Or you can append full_name attribute to you model and search it in the front end,